# Finding maximal elements of a poset's subset

Tags: algorithm, poset

The problem is the following:
Given a poset's subset S find the maximal elements of S.

For example consider the hass diagram of the poset in http://ndp.jct.ac.il/tutorials/Discrete/node34.html. Given a subset of it ex: {12, 2, 8} the maximal elements are 12 and 8.

I do not know if I describe precisly the problem. I think the problem might involves some sorting or computation of transitive closure but I am a little confused.

Could you give me some approach for a fast algorithm? I would like to keep it in O(n^2)

Thanks.

A little clarification. My application is using RDF graphs. Two nodes are comparable if there exists a specific edge that represent the < relation. Two nodes might be comparable if there is such an explicit relation or an implicit transitive one.

So assume that the hass diagram is exactly my RDF graph. If I start from 2 doing a depth-first search how do I know that the 8 and 12 are not comparable? They might not be explicitly but they might be implicitly.

Comment: If two nodes are comparable wrt. the ordering relation, then at least one of them has to have a successor node that "transfers" the ordering relation, right?

Comment: Yes that is right. However if you have the path a-b-c, a and c are "implicitly" comparable. Based on that I suspect that I have to compute the transitive closure of every node of the subset and make the "cleaning" of the comparable elements.

Comment: Assuming a-b implies a<b, then c is still a maximal element of {a,b,c} in that case because it has no successor. a is not a maximal element because it has a successor, b.

Comment: Never mind my last comment. Here, too, DFS traversal can find the right answer, but not if you run it on the subset {a,b,c,f} and disregard the rest of the successor relation.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this in linear time if you know a minimal subset of the ordering relation: regard it as a DAG, then do a depth-first traversal to find all vertices that have no successor.